# for loop with array pointers, setting values to the pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm completely new to C and have to work with pointers which are kind of confusing right now.

My task is to rewrite a code:

```
const int length = 3;
int a[3] = { 2, 1, 3 };
int* p = a;
for (int i = length - 1; i > 0; i--)
    a[i - 1] += a[i];
```

so it doesn't use the '[ ]' of the Arrays anymore but instead is using pointers.

My first try:

```
const int length = 3;
int a[3] = { 2, 1, 3 };
int* p = a;
for (int i = length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    *(p - 1) += *p;
    p--;
}
```

So I know this one isn't working but I don't know how to work properly with pointers. When do you use the `*` and when not? What does it exactly mean? Is `*` the value behind the pointer and p itself the address? How do I decrement/increment a pointer to go to the next address?

Thanks in advance

Comment: btw, Where  is `+=` in your code `a[i - 1] += a[i];` doens't looks same as of `*(p - 1) = *p;`

Comment: Thanks. edited my question. forgot it sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Mistake

Pointer `p` is already pointing to first element of array, after decrement operation (`--p`), `p` starts pointing to a location that is not allocated (outside the array) — causes undefined behaviors.

#### Basic Approach

First you need to understand that en array expression `a[i]` is equivalent to `*(a + i)` that is also equivalent to `*(p + i)` if `p` is pointer to first element of array. Further, `a[i - 1]` can also be written as `*(a + i - 1)` and that is equivalent to expression `*(p + i - 1)`.

In declaration of `p`:

```
int* p = a;
```

array name decays to address of first element in array (that is same as of `&a[0]`).

Now, following is reverse loop - iterating backwards from last position in array.

```
for (int i = length - 1; i > 0; i--)
    a[i - 1] += a[i];
```

it can also be written as:

```
for (int i = length - 1; i > 0; i--)
    *(a + i - 1) += *(a + i);
```

and so can be written as

```
for (int i = length - 1; i > 0; i--)
    *(p + i - 1) += *(p + i);
```

#### Correction in your Code

This is just a simple translation of your code in the form of `p` pointer to first element.

Lets we take a new approach and understands what does actually the loop do:

```
for (int i = length - 1; i > 0; i--)
    a[i - 1] += a[i];
```

Operation  `a[i - 1] += a[i];` is same as `a[i - 1] = a[i - 1] + a[i];`. That means — in loop, in each iteration, value at `i` th position is added to `i - 1` where value of `i` is `2 >= i > 1`. See:

```
for (int i = 3 - 1; i > 0; i--)
//           ^^ == 2 
    a[i - 1] = a[i - 1] + a[i];
```

so, if initial value of array is: `a[3] = { 2, 1, 3 };` then each iteration is:

```
    // 0       1        2
      { 2,      1,       3 };

      i = 2  
      a[2 - 1] = a[2 - 1] + a[2];
      a[1] = a[1] + a[2]
      { 2,      4,       3 }; 

      i = 1 
      a[1 - 1] = a[1 - 1] + a[1];
      a[0] = a[0] + a[1]
      { 6,      4,       3 };
```

In the above loop, you iterates back and adds current `i` index value to previous index. Note because in each iteration you access one element at `i - 1` so loop has to be break at `i == 1` or we can say at `i > 0`.

lets rewrite correct code in the way you wanted to be write:

```
const int length = 3;
int a[3] = { 2, 1, 3 };
int* p = a + length - 1; // now `p` points to `&a[2]`
for (int i = length - 1; i > 0; i--)
    *(p - 1) += *p;
    --p;
```

#### Better Approach

Now, still this is quite verbose code, we can improve it as follows:

```
int a[3] = { 2, 1, 3 };
for (int* p = &a[2]; p != a; --p)
   *(p - 1) += *p;
```

#### Better Code

```
int a[] = { 2, 1, 3 };
int length = sizeof(a) / sizeof(*a);
for (int* p = a + length - 1 ; p != a; --p)
   *(p - 1) += *p;
```

Give it a Try!!

Comment: Thank you very much! Really appreciate the explanation of this topic!

Comment: @NhatNienne you accepted answer before I could complete. Your approach was correct but a small mistake I corrected your code.